# How to find last inserted row in SQL server without identity column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have created table like below:

```
create table EmployeeDetails
(
    id int,
    name varchar(50),
    designation varchar(50),
    ReportingTo int
)
```

And inserted rows like this:

```
insert into EmployeeDetails values(1, 'A', 'Developer', 3)
insert into EmployeeDetails values(5, 'E', 'CEO', 5)
insert into EmployeeDetails values(2, 'B', 'Developer', 3)
insert into EmployeeDetails values(3, 'C', 'Manager', 4)
insert into EmployeeDetails values(4, 'D', 'S.Manager', 5)
```

My question is: how can I identify the last inserted row in the table?

Used queries:

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('EmployeeDetails')
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

But I still didn't find the answer.

Replies are always welcome

Comment: So, which are you asking for?  MySQL, MSSQL, or SQLite?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Too many products tagged...

Comment: Your id column is not an `IDENTITY` field so you can't do that. You are explicitly inserting the id, so you already know the last id used. You should clarify your question.

Comment: My car has a flat tire. I have to go to the Mumbai center city, and I don't want to fix my flat tire. What is the best route to Mumbai if I'm driving on the bare rim? :-) Seriously, tracking the most recent insert without an autoincrementing surrogate primary key column is difficult, uncomfortable, and unreliable.

Comment: @squillman using MSSQL.

Comment: @gordonlinoff thanks MSSQL

Answer (score 10):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of tables in relational databases. They represent *unordered* sets. So, there is no "last row" in a table.  The information on the ordering of rows has to be included when you create the table and/or load data into it.

In SQL Server, the simplest method is an identity column. That is why many tables are defined as:

```
create table EmployeeDetails (
    id int identity primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    designation varchar(50),
    ReportingTo int
);
```

You can also add default insertion time columns:

```
create table EmployeeDetails (
    id int identity primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    designation varchar(50),
    ReportingTo int,
    CreatedAt datetime default gettime()
);
```

However, you can have multiple rows with the same `datetime` value.

Answer (score 4):

You also can use rowversion like below,if you add a column

```
CREATE TABLE MyTest (myKey int  
    ,myValue int, RV rowversion);  
GO   
INSERT INTO MyTest (myKey, myValue) VALUES (1, 0);  
GO   
INSERT INTO MyTest (myKey, myValue) VALUES (2, 0); 

select * from mytest order by rv desc
```

Note:
This always give the last row inserted/Updated

**References:**
[rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql)

Comment: please provide attribution to the source of your code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql

Comment: @Tanner: Did it,i always do this,but not sure why i missed in this instance

Comment: no worries, only saw this as someone copied this answer on another post, that I've already flagged: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191654/57475

Answer (score 3):

Add fields of type datetime with name CreateDate and UpdateDate in your table, when you insert record in your table set their value for `getdate()`

After that you can run queries:

```
Select top 10 * from YourTable Order By CreateDate DESC
```

Or for last updated

```
Select top 10 * from YourTable Order By UpdateDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find my answer as below. Hope this may help you.

Add one more column to store record creation date/time as below.

```
create table EmployeeDetails
 (
 id int,
 name varchar(50),
 designation varchar(50),
 ReportingTo int,
 CreatedOn datetime
 )
```

After table creation and inserting records write/execute query (here inner query is used) as below

```
select
*
from EmployeeDetails 
where CreatedOn = (select max(CreatedOn) from EmployeeDetails )
```