# How to select particular data from a table?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me how to select last data with some condition from my table. But, I don't need to `LIMIT` my data, or search for any `MAX` or `MIN` data.

Comment: Supplier  varchar(75) , Jenis  varchar(100)  ,   Ukuran_Zipper  varchar(10)  , Kode_Warna  varchar(10)    Warna_Basic  varchar(50) , Bahan_Gigi  varchar(50) , Warna_Gigi  varchar(50) , Ukuran_Gigi  varchar(10) , Current_Stock  int(50) , Stock_In  int(10) , Stock_Out  int(10),Harga_Beli  int(10) , Keterangan  varchar(5000) , Stock_Akhir  int(10)

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question can you add sample data and expected output as text to the question (or sqlfiddle) and can you translate the column names to English.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from MYTABLE where COLUMN_NAME ="toto"

This is the base of all sql request if you want add a condition use AND or OR operators in the where clause

Comment: i just need to show 1 last data from a column... and my table don't have any ID or Unique number

Comment: You can t here is a good explanation of why :

https://stackoverflow.com/q/40020319/9630748

Comment: you can also add a a date time on every field with a constant value and add a real value on row added from now